# Label alignment

Tags: tables

I have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf, labelsep=newline, justification=centering, textfont=it]{caption}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, siunitx}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[referable,para]{threeparttablex}
\usepackage[scale=1,textheight=27cm, textwidth=15cm, margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{interval}
\usepackage{pbox}
\sisetup{group-separator={,}, table-format=1.3, table-space-text-post=***, 
table-number-alignment =center}
\newcommand*{\MyIndent}
{\hspace*{1.5cm}}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D..{#1}}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}[p] %table 1
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{18pt}
\centering
\normalsize
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Summary Statistics\label{sumstat}}
\begin{tabular}{l*{8}{d{2.3}}}
\toprule \toprule

&\multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Dem}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{No Dem.}} & \mc{\multirow{2}[1]{*}{Test for difference in means}}\\ 
\cmidrule(lr){2-4}\cmidrule(lr){5-7}
Variable                                                                                                                    &\mc{Obs.}          &\mc{Mean}          &\mc{S.D.}          &\mc{Obs.}          &\mc{Mean}          &\mc{S.D.} & \\ 
\midrule
$(ln)y_{i,t}$                                                                                               &\mc{9.31}          &\mc{8.79}          &\mc{9.56}          &\mc{-0.77}         &\mc{\phantom{-}-8.20} & & \mc{2.3}\\[1.5ex]
$PC_{i,t}$                                                                                                  &\mc{6.35}          &\mc{1.71}          &\mc{8.62}          &\mc{-6.91}             &\mc{-69.72} &&\\[1.5ex]
$(ln)s_{i,t}$                                                                                               &\mc{1.01}          &\mc{0.85}          &\mc{1.08}          &\mc{-0.23}             &\mc{\phantom{-}-5.86}  & &\\[1.5ex]
$(ln)(n+\delta+g_{T}+g_{GB})_{i,t}$ &&&&&&&\\
\bottomrule \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}
\small
      \item[]{\textit{Notes}: In column (a) we report the means of the main variables used in our analysis. In columns (b) and (c) we differentiate between countries with $PC\leq 5$ and those with $PC>5$. In column (d) we report the difference between the means for those two groups of countries, while in column (e) we display the t--test for the null hypothesis that the previous difference is equal to 0. Our sample consists of 119 countries spanning over the time period 1980--2010 (819 country--year observations). The panel is unbalanced. The countries included in our sample are: Albania, Algeria, Angola, Argentina, Australia, Austria, Bahrain, Bangladesh, Belgium, Benin, Bolivia, Botswana, Brazil, Bulgaria, Burkina Faso, Burundi, Cambodia, Cameroon, Canada, Central African Republic, Chad, Chile, China, Colombia, Congo, Dem. Rep., Congo, Republic Of, Costa Rica, Cote d'Ivoire, Cyprus, Czech Republic, Denmark, Dominican Republic, Ecuador, Egypt, El Salvador, Ethiopia, Fiji, Finland, France, Gabon, Germany, Ghana, Greece, Guatemala, Guinea-Bissau, Guyana, Haiti, Honduras, Hungary, India, Indonesia, Iran, Ireland, Israel, Italy, Jamaica, Japan, Jordan, Kenya, Korea, Republic of, Kuwait, Lesotho, Madagascar, Malawi, Malaysia, Mali, Mauritania, Mauritius, Mexico, Mongolia, Morocco, Mozambique, Namibia, Nepal, Netherlands, New Zealand, Nicaragua, Niger, Nigeria, Norway, Oman, Pakistan, Panama, Papua New Guinea, Paraguay, Peru, Philippines, Poland, Portugal, Qatar, Romania, Russia, Rwanda, Saudi Arabia, Senegal, Sierra Leone, Singapore, South Africa, Spain, Sri Lanka, Sweden, Switzerland, Syria, Taiwan, Tanzania, Thailand, Togo, Trinidad \& Tobago, Tunisia, Turkey, Uganda, United Arab Emirates, United KingdomUnited States, Uruguay, Venezuela, Vietnam, Zambia, Zimbabwe.}
      \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

I would like to have "Test for difference in means" in the last column over two rows. I tried `\mintab` but I was unsuccessful.

Any suggestion? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this? Note that I've removed most of the `\mc` "wrappers". Note also that I've provided a bit more structure to the otherwise extremely lengthy (and, dare I say it, exceedingly dull) `tablenotes` material.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf, labelsep=newline, 
            justification=centering, 
            textfont=it]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, siunitx}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\usepackage[referable,para,flushleft]{threeparttablex}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,ragged2e} % <-- new
\usepackage{interval,pbox}
\newcommand*{\MyIndent}{\hspace*{1.5cm}}
\usepackage{array,dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D..{#1}}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\newcommand\mytab[1]{%
   \smash[b]{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}}
\hyphenation{bur-kina} % not "burk-ina"...

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable} %table 1

\centering
\normalsize

\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Summary Statistics\label{sumstat}}
\begin{tabular}{@{} l *{3}{d{1.2}} *{3}{d{2.2}} d{1.1} @{}}
\toprule

Variable & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Dem.}} 
         & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{No Dem.}} 
         & \multicolumn{1}{c@{}}{%
             \mytab{Test for \\diff.\ in means}}\\ 
\cmidrule(lr){2-4}\cmidrule(lr){5-7} 
& \mc{Obs.} & \mc{Mean} & \mc{S.D.} 
& \mc{Obs.} & \mc{Mean} & \mc{S.D.}\\ 
\midrule
$\ln y_{i,t}$ & 9.31 & 8.79 & 9.56 & -0.77 & -8.20 & & 2.3 \\[1.5ex]
$PC_{i,t}$ & 6.35 & 1.71 & 8.62 & -6.91 & -69.72 &         \\[1.5ex]
$\ln s_{i,t}$ & 1.01 & 0.85 & 1.08 & -0.23 & -5.86 &       \\[1.5ex]
$\ln (n+\delta+g_{T}+g_{GB})_{i,t}$ &&&&&&\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\small\RaggedRight
\begin{tablenotes}
\item\textit{Notes}: In column (a) we report the means of the main 
variables used in our analysis. 

In columns (b) and (c)~we differentiate between countries with 
\mbox{$PC\leq5$} and those with \mbox{$PC>5$}. 

In column~(d) we report the difference between the means for those 
two groups of countries, while in column~(e) we display the $t$-test 
for the null hypothesis that the previous difference is equal to~0. 

Our sample consists of 119 countries spanning the time period from 
1980 to 2010 (819 country-year observations). The panel is unbalanced. 

The countries included in our sample are: Albania, Algeria, Angola, 
Argentina, Australia, Austria, Bahrain, Bangladesh, Belgium, Benin, 
Bolivia, Botswana, Brazil, Bulgaria, Burkina Faso, Burundi, Cambodia, 
Cameroon, Canada, Central African Republic, Chad, Chile, China, Colombia, 
Congo, Dem.\ Rep.; Congo, Republic of; Costa Rica, Cote d'Ivoire, Cyprus, 
Czech Republic, Denmark, Dominican Republic, Ecuador, Egypt, El Salvador, 
Ethiopia, Fiji, Finland, France, Gabon, Germany, Ghana, Greece, Guatemala, 
Guinea-Bissau, Guyana, Haiti, Honduras, Hungary, India, Indonesia, Iran, 
Ireland, Israel, Italy, Jamaica, Japan, Jordan, Kenya; Korea, Republic of; 
Kuwait, Lesotho, Madagascar, Malawi, Malaysia, Mali, Mauritania, Mauritius, 
Mexico, Mongolia, Morocco, Mozambique, Namibia, Nepal, Netherlands, 
New Zealand, Nicaragua, Niger, Nigeria, Norway, Oman, Pakistan, Panama, 
Papua New Guinea, Paraguay, Peru, Philippines, Poland, Portugal, Qatar, 
Romania, Russia, Rwanda, Saudi Arabia, Senegal, Sierra Leone, Singapore, 
South Africa, Spain, Sri Lanka, Sweden, Switzerland, Syria, Taiwan, 
Tanzania, Thailand, Togo, Trinidad \& Tobago, Tunisia, Turkey, Uganda, 
United Arab Emirates, United Kingdom, United States, Uruguay, Venezuela,
Vietnam, Zambia, Zimbabwe.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```